# If selection = ?..then, how to decrease the a value of an integer attribute?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2

i am working with a reservation system and i am having problem with the constraints.. i have a list of cottages with a number of cottages vacant.. a working sytem i swhen the customer reserve a cottage the number of vacant cottage need to decrease.. please help me i have here some codes i started... and an image to help you understand my explanation..

**what i want to accomplish here is:**

Before a reservation: Cottage Availability: 5

if i fill up information & select "small cottage" and create reservation the availability value will -1.

After a reservation: Cottage availability: 4

**form.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for(@reservation) do |f| %>

  <%= f.label :reservation_date %><br>
  <%= f.date_select :reservation_date %>

  <%= f.label :customer_name %><br>
  <%= f.text_field :customer_name %>

  <%= f.label :address%><br>
  <%= f.text_field :address %>

  <%= f.label :contact_no %><br>
  <%= f.text_field :contact_no %>

  <%= f.label :cottage_class %><br>
  <%= f.select :cottage_id, options_for_select( Cottage.all.map { |g| [g.name, g.id]}) %>

  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

**schema.rb**

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20160514141006) do

  create_table "cottages", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "rates"
    t.integer  "no_of_vacant_cottage"
    t.datetime "created_at",   null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",   null: false
  end

  create_table "reservations", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.date     "reservation_date"
    t.string   "customer_name"
    t.string   "address"
    t.string   "contact_no"
    t.datetime "created_at",       null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",       null: false
    t.integer  "cottage_id"
  end

  add_index "reservations", ["cottage_id"], name: "index_reservations_on_cottage_id"

end
```

**reservation.rb**

```
class Reservation < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :customer_name, :presence => true
  validates :address, :presence => true
  validates :contact_no, :presence => true

  belongs_to :cottage
end
```

**cottage.rb**

```
class Cottage < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :reservations
end
```

[Form and list of cottages existing on the database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ldXA0.png)

Comment: 2 things here : you put multiple ruby-on-rails tags (ruby-on-rails-3 ruby-on-rails-4 ruby-on-rails-3.2), which version are you using ? Second, I have troubles understanding your system of reservations. Shouldn't your availability be date-specific ? By date-specific I mean your availability varies from date to date based on reservations for that date. For me it does not make sense to have an availability field in your cottage model, but your cottage model could have a method availability(date) that would return the availability for a specific date.

Comment: @Pholochtairze sorry i will rename it to "number of vacant cottages" [small, medium, big]

Comment: @Pholochtairze my problem is focusing only on how to decrease the value of no_of_vacant_cottage after i reserve a cottage..

Comment: for example: i have 25 vacant small cottages, and when the customer reserve a 1 small cottage, the vacant small cottages now is 24..

Comment: Thats useless cause it tells you nothing about when the cottages are availble. Say someone books 5 months in advance - your availablity metric would still display that it is not available next week.

Comment: FYI, an English sentence starts with a capital letter, and ends with a single period, not two.

Comment: @max i just want to give the customer on how many vacant cottages left..? AND I THINK the availability of each cottages is my problem later.. im a just seeking for help on how to decrease the value of the no_of_vacant_cottage.. an if else statement will do.. i just dont know where to start..

Comment: @sawa Sorry, but i am not good in english. I am happy for you because you are perfect in english language.

Comment: Yeah, but that depends on what date the customer is trying to book - if I am trying to book seats in movie theater for a movie tomorrow the current occupancy is totally irrelevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't necessarily see the point of what you try to do, but still I'll try to answer your specific problen.

First, we want to initialize the number of vacant cottages to 5, for this when you create the table you can put :

```
create_table "cottages", force: :cascade do |t|
  # ...
  t.integer  "no_of_vacant_cottage", default: 5
  #...
end
```

Or if you cannot directly change your migration you could make a migration especially for that :

```
change_column :cottages, :no_of_vacant_cottage, :integer, :default => 5
```

Okay, so now our `no_of_vacant_cottage` column is by default set to 5. Now, whenever you make a new reservation you want to decrease the corresponding cottage's no_of_vacant_cottage column by 1. You can use a [`callback`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html) for that. What you probably want here is `after_save`.

So in your reservation model you will have something that looks like this:

```
class Reservation < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :customer_name, :presence => true
  validates :address, :presence => true
  validates :contact_no, :presence => true
  belongs_to :cottage

  after_save :decrement_no_of_vacant_cottage

  def decrement_no_of_vacant_cottage
    c = self.cottage
    c.update(no_of_vacant_cottage: c.no_of_vacant_cottage -1)
  end
end
```

Please note that it will do this every time the reservation is **saved** and that even if you change the cottage_id of your reservation the old cottage will still keep his "-1". I let you handle those cases now that you know what callbacks are.

You added some question in the comments "what code to notice the customer after a reservation or after c.update(availability: c.availability - 1) message/notice here message like "thank you for your reservation" ". This is quite simple, you just handle that logic in your controller. So in your controller you probably had something like that:

```
if @reservation.save
  # some code
else
  # handle the unsuccessful save
end
```

That will become:

```
if @reservation.save
  notification_function
  # notification_function could be for instance flash[:notice]="Thank you for your reservation."
  # additional code code
else
  # handle the unsuccessful save
end
```

Comment: @CrossGozon You're welcome.Since it seems you're new here, I should tell you that when your problem is solved you can mark it as an accepted answer with the little green check (just under the number on the left of my answer) and/or vote for my answer ;) See : http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147531/how-mark-my-question-as-answered-on-stackoverflow

Comment: what code to notice the customer after a reservation or after c.update(availability: c.availability - 1) <!-- message/notice here message like "thank you for your reservation" -->

Comment: @CrossGozon added a hint on how to notify the user, at the bottom of my answer. But the exact implementation of how you notify the user is hard to tell without seeing your application, here I just wrote a method called "notification_function" that you will need to replace with your own logic. I proposed in the comments to use flash[:notice] but the implementation is up to you.